# Can't connect to SVN - can't find the file specified

Tags: svn, unix, version-control, tortoisesvn

I've set up svn repo on remote server

```
# svn info
Path: .
URL: file:///root/svn/dadilja/trunk
Repository Root: file:///root/svn/dadilja
```

I'm trying to do using TortoiseSVN

`svn+ssh://USERNAME@SERVER:PORT/root/svn/dadilja/trunk`

and getting

> "Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>    'svn+ssh://USERNAME@SERVER:PORT/root/svn/dadilja/branches/dev'
>   Can't create tunnel: The system cannot find the file specified.

I have no idea what to do? `/root/svn/dadilja/trunk` path doesn't really exist. In `/root/svn/dadilja` I have stuff such as `db`, `locks`, and `conf`. However checkout on same machine works fine using

```
svn co file:///path
```

---

**Edit:** ommiting port doesn't fix it

Comment: Did you setup svnserve on the SVN server? See http://civicactions.com/blog/2010/may/25/how_set_svn_repository_7_simple_steps

Comment: nope, I might do that if svn+ssh approach fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not specify the port in the svn url, this is AFAIK not supported.

The only way I know to use an SSH server on a non-standard port is to generally set the non-standard port via the file `.subversion/config`. There you can modify the ssh command and thus specify the port.

```
[tunnels]
sshtunnel = ssh -p <port>
```

http://linuxsysadminblog.com/2009/08/using-svnssh-with-a-non-standard-ssh-port/

Comment: Thanks for hinting at port error. I'm actually using TortoiseSVN for Windows as client, so [this page](http://www.vectorns.com/blog/11-tortoisesvn-over-ssh-on-windows-via-putty) was more helpful in my case

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right URL? Your "this page" is not related to TortoiseSVN at all...

Comment: it's suddently getting redirected, as though the page no longer exists. let's leave it be for a while maybe it comes back.. I'll take a look in a few days and remove it if it's still redirecting